# How to replace HDD with SSD in laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I want to replace HDD with SSD in my laptop. How to choose right type of SSD, which parameters of laptop should I know?

I've found some similar questions, but they are too old and technologies could change during these years

UPD: laptop model is [Samsung np355v4c](http://www.samsung.com/ru/support/model/NP355V4C-S01RU), it's 3 years old, but I wanted to know how to do it with all other possible laptops or check if it is impossible

Comment: Can you give more details such as laptop model?

Comment: There are many tutorials online, Google can be your friend here.  This kind of question, looking for tutorials or product recommendation, is off topic here.

Comment: @acejavelin sorry, it was unclear from FAQ that these type of questions are offtopic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You will need a 2.5" drive for a laptop - all SSD drives you will be looking at will be 2.5" so no issues there.
2. Unless your laptop is very old you will need a SATA drive - all SSDs you will be able to buy will be SATA III.  Make sure your current drive connects using SATA.  You can check this in the laptop specifications or by opening up the body and physically checking the connectors (watch a tutorial before you do this).
3. The only real issue you will need to consider is the size of the drive.  See how much space your current drive is using and get a drive that is bigger so that you can fit everything onto it.  Alternatively you could backup and keep your data on an external drive and just use the new SDD for your Operating System and programs - but you might find this does not save you much time in the long run as you will need to keep using the External Drive to access your files.
4. One possibility to briefly consider is whether your laptop is able to have 2 separate 2.5" drives installed, but this is unlikely as these laptops are relatively rare.

Comment: Thanks, points all is ok about points 1 and 2. SSD of 750+ GB is completely unacceptable because it cost more than my entire laptop. Maybe I'll later check if it is possible to replace ODD with HDD

Comment: I have old laptop with SATA 1. I think hybrid drive is the best solution for so old laptop. I put in SSHD 1TB (8GB SSD) 
which cost ~ $60. Average transfer previously was 60 MB/s and is now 120 MB/s. Everything now loads faster.